# Why did Nog ask Vic, “Do you dream?”

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In [DS9: It's Only a Paper Moon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/It%27s_Only_a_Paper_Moon_(episode)) Nog asks the hologram character Vic Fontaine,

> "Do you dream?"

Is this a reference to HAL from *2001: a Space Odyssey*?

Comment: Curiosity, perhaps?

Comment: Would it be *2001* or *2010* that would be the reference? In the movie version of *2010*, Dr. Chandra reveals to HAL that HAL and the *Discovery* might be destroyed when *Discovery* is left behind, and HAL asks Dr. Chandra, "Will I dream?"

Comment: Do androids dream of electric sheep? In an alternate universe, Vic is an android, not a hologram.

Comment: @barrycarter In an alternate universe, Vic would be an enjoyable character. I really hate him. He just brings morbid songs and horrendous story lines. It would have been a novelty if Frank Sinatra Jr played him, but without that novelty, he's nothing!